# How do i compute this integral for a moment generating function?

Tags: probability, integration, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to find the moment generating function of a random variable but I'm not sure how to compute this integral:

for $t<1$ How do i compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} x^2 e^{tx-x} \,dx$

Comment: Integration by parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
  & u=\frac{1}{2}{{x}^{2}},\quad dv={{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}dx \\ 
 & =\left. \frac{1}{2}{{x}^{2}}\frac{{{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}}{t-1} \right|_{0}^{\infty }-\int_{0}^{\infty }{\overbrace{x}^{u}\overbrace{\frac{{{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}}{t-1}}^{dv}dx} \\ 
 & =\left. \frac{1}{2}{{x}^{2}}\frac{{{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}}{t-1} \right|_{0}^{\infty }-\left( \left. x\frac{{{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}}{{{\left( t-1 \right)}^{2}}} \right|_{0}^{\infty }-\int_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}}{{{\left( t-1 \right)}^{2}}}dx} \right) \\ 
 & =\left. \frac{1}{2}{{x}^{2}}\frac{{{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}}{t-1} \right|_{0}^{\infty }-\left. x\frac{{{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}}{{{\left( t-1 \right)}^{2}}} \right|_{0}^{\infty }+\left. \frac{{{e}^{\left( t-1 \right)x}}}{{{\left( t-1 \right)}^{3}}} \right|_{0}^{\infty } \\ 
 & =\frac{-1}{{{\left( t-1 \right)}^{3}}} \\ 
\end{align}$$